# MongoDB C# How to Update GridFS File and metadata?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

Need a solution to to see if the grid file exist and then update the file with metadata.

I am using the solution below. but want a better one.

Don't mind having separate Update and Delete methods.

Thanks

```
Public Class storedXYZ 

    Property Data As Stream

    Property MetaData As storedXYZMetaData

End Class

Public Sub SaveStoredXYZ(storedXYZ As StoredXYZ) 


        Dim MongoGridFSCreateOptions As New MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSCreateOptions

        Dim qry As IMongoQuery


        qry = Query.EQ("metadata.StoredXYZId", BsonValue.Create(storedXYZ.MetaData.StoredXYZ.ToString()))


        Dim gridFile As MongoGridFSFileInfo = mdbGridFS.FindOne(qry)


        If gridFile IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim mongoStream As MongoGridFSStream

            MongoGridFSCreateOptions.Metadata = storedXYZ.MetaData.ToBsonDocument

            mongoStream = gridFile.OpenWrite()

            ''Convert MongoStream to MemoryStream
            Dim fs As Stream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(9999) {}
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
            Do
                bytesRead = storedXYZ.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                mongoStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            Loop While bytesRead > 0

            mongoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            mongoStream.Position = 0


            mdbGridFS.SetMetadata(gridFile, storedAXYZ.MetaData.ToBsonDocument)

        Else

            MongoGridFSCreateOptions.Metadata = storedXYZ.MetaData.ToBsonDocument

            Dim fileinfo As MongoGridFSFileInfo

            fileinfo = mdbGridFS.Upload(storedXYZ.Data, storedXYZ.MetaData.Name, MongoGridFSCreateOptions)

        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to overwrite the current file why not just fire off a delete command and then re-upload the file and update the document to the old ones Id?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that while in the middle of updating the existing file it is in an inconsistent state (the length and md5 values in the fs.files metadata are not valid until you close the file again, not to mention that the data is changing). This means that other processes could see an intermediate and inconsistent version of the file, and the update crashes for some reason the GridFS file is permanently damaged. On the other hand, updating an existing file in place can be a huge performance gain when only a few bytes are changing.

Comment: Above solution works , but wanted a better ones. I thought of delete and upload again. but imagine this is a bulk insert of files. Before saving it has to check if the file exist.

Answer (score 0):

MongoGridFS Upload method gets a new version of the file when you upload a file using an existing file name.

Using OpenWrite with an existing file name updates the file in place. The C# driver is the only driver that allows to update a GridFS file in place.

[More information here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-266)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fs.files and fs.chnuks collections as any other collection but you have to be careful to keep important for GridFS data untouched.